# Why that centroids do not change in K-means imply that assignment does not change?

Tags: k-means

I understand how to prove that assignment does not change lead to that centroids do not change, but I do not feel it is straightforward to prove or disprove it from another direction.

Comment: Can you tell us what you understand about the rule for assignment given centroids?

Comment: It will assign the points to nearest centroid each turn. I am thinking whether there is a case that centroids do not change, but the assignments of each cluster change, and the points get and lost for each cluster are balanced this iteration. Although my intuition tells me this case does not exist, I do not know how to disprove it. I can disprove it when there is only one dimension, but not straightforward to map it to N dimensions

Comment: How would which centroid is closest to a given point change?

Comment: Are you thinking of cases where there are ties, i.e. the closest centroid (to some given point) is not unique?

Comment: Not really, I am not thinking the ties.